# Select all .ts files recursively to generate UML Diagram

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, uml

I want to generate the class diagram of my project using the tsuml package

I am trying to generate a UML diagram of my application using the tsUML package. According to the website, the command *tsuml --glob ./src/**/*.ts*  would be sufficient to recursively retrieve all files and generate the diagram with the dependencies between the files. However, the result I'm having is
that only files in the app directory are being selected. How do I make all files recursively selected from the src directory?

```
$ tsuml --glob ./src/**/*.ts
Matched files:
./src/app/app.component.spec.ts

- mycrudapp
--/src
-- --/enviroments
-- --/app
-- -- --/utils
-- -- --/crud
-- -- -- --/create
-- -- -- --/edit
-- -- -- --/list
-- -- -- --/view
```

I also tried the command below but it didn't work:

$ `tsuml --glob ./src/**/**/*.ts`

The command is expected to generate a UML class diagram as in [this image](https://github.com/remojansen/TsUML/raw/master/assets/uml_diagram.svg?sanitize=true) from the .ts files.

Answer (score 0):

Try escaping your glob:

```
tsuml --glob './src/**/**/*.ts'
```

should do the trick!